# E2E Testing of event handlers in NestJS

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, e2e-testing, eventemitter

How can you test that the proper event handler was called after specific event was emitted by an endpoint? (E2E integration test)

It looks like jest does not call EventEmitter2 handlers.

Thx.

Comment: I think that you can just call the function on the method